# cardinality's info of an xml element

Tags: java, xml, xsd, cardinality

given a validated xml file, how to get the xsd-authorized cardinality of one of its elements in java ?

I've searched in xml validation API but nothing seems to do the job.

thanks a lot

Comment: Would would have to dig into the XSD (xerces has an XSD model https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/package-summary.html). But this is not a trival task, you first need to reconsile the location in the XML file with a location in the XSD - which is much harder than it sounds. You may find some hooks in the xerces parser that allow you to get the xsd object its using to validate the current XML object, but I'm not familiar with any...